# Open instagram particular account page from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Using flutter how can i open particular instagram page by clicking one button... If app is available then open that particular page in instagram app otherwise open tht in website or show error message tht app not installed

Answer (score 1):

Instagram does not have any official SDK from flutter.

However, you could use any library that opens urls (I personally use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)).

The url for opening an Instagram account is:

```
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/_u/$account';
```

where account is the username of the Instagram user (without the @).